# Increment the occurrence of all the digits in a string perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to increment the occurrence of all the digits in a string perl
eg. if I have string as $str = "go to page number 34 annd read the 3rd line"
it should be changed to  $str = "go to page number 35 and read the 4rd line".

I tried using

```
$str =~ s/[\d]/$&+1/g
```

but it gives output as string i.e.  "go to page number 34+1 and read the 3+1rd line"

Answer (score 9):

How about this:

```
$ echo "foo 1 bar 2" | perl -pE 's/(\d+)/$1+1/ge'
foo 2 bar 3
```

The point is the `e` regex option that treats the replacement part as an expression.

Comment: Also, be sure to use a capture group () and $1 as the answer suggests, instead of $& as in the question. $& results in severe performance penalties in most versions of Perl 5.