# Match numbers in a string and add 1 to them in R

Tags: r, regex, string, numbers

I need to increase the numbers following "abc" by 1 in a string

> From: "abc1 + abc34 + def7" 
>   To: "abc2 + abc35 + def7"

This failed attempt:

```
string <- "abc1 + abc34 + def7"
gsub("abc([0-9]+)","abc\\1\\+1",string)
```

Gave me this:

> "abc1+1 + abc34+1 + def7"

Because the replacement is treated as a string, not as an expression.

It seems possible in Perl ([perl example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11878494/increment-the-occurrence-of-all-the-digits-in-a-string-perl)). Is it possible in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `gsubfn`; Capture `abc` and the digits after it, create a function as replacement where you can increase the matched digit by one and paste it with the captured `abc`:

```
library(gsubfn)
# here the first argument x is the first captured group, and y is the second captured group
gsubfn("(abc)(\\d+)", ~ paste(x, as.numeric(y) + 1, sep=""), string)
# [1] "abc2 + abc35 + def7"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set `perl=TRUE` and use `regmatches` to accomplish this, it's just a little ugly:

```
> m <- gregexpr('(?<=abc)[0-9]+', string, perl=TRUE)
> regmatches(string, m)
[[1]]
[1] "1"  "34"

> regmatches(string,m)[[1]] <- as.character(as.numeric(regmatches(string,m)[[1]]) + 1)
> string
[1] "abc2 + abc35 + def7
```